# Meaning of "connecting circuit to the ground"

Tags: circuit-analysis, ground

What does "connect a circuit to ground" mean? Someone told me that all ground points are connected to each other so we can connect the two points ? 
The original circuit is the one with the resistor R3 connected to the ground. 
I'm a beginner and I want to know what does "connect a circuit to ground" mean?If it has no influence why would one do this ?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Who says you can take the left circuit and cross connect the points that you have. The symbols don't look like ground symbols to me and they may even have different voltages on them but, your pictures are unclear. A bit more punctuation and beginning sentences with a capital letter might give your question more credibility also. No need to thank anyone.

Comment: First pic seems odd, because both ends of R3 are grounded (!) Anyway, according to the first pic, (B) is ground (look at the GND symbol). For the second pic, tying both ends of R3 together is correct. For the third one; since both ends of R3 are connected to the same junction, R3 can be replaced with an empty wire.

Comment: Somehow the image seems to be missing?  (Or is it just me?)

Comment: please dont post the image again for copyright reasons .....

Comment: Ground is just a point that you get to pick that is assumed to be 0 volts. Choose wisely.

Answer (score 1):

> In electrical engineering, ground or earth is the reference point in an electrical circuit from which voltages are measured, a common return path for electric current, or a direct physical connection to the Earth.

I do not see why you would need two ground connections (if they are) in the left picture.  You would want to measure the potential at any point in the circuit with reference to another point or ground normally.  Earth or ground is usually the other point you would use.  Only one ground connection is needed to measure potential voltage at any reference in the circuit.  You may need more ground planes (connections) if you deal with AC versus DC, different potentials, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first two circuits (left and center) are equivalent. Both sides of R3 are connected to each other by means of "ground".  That renders R3 "shorted" or zero ohms.

The circuit on the right is NOT equivalent because it fails to show that R3 is effectively shorted by connecting both ends together (through "ground").

In this case (and in most common usage) "ground" only means some common reference point for the circuit. It does not necessarily mean that it is connected to Earth, etc.